# nextjs install fail, "npm run dev" don't work

Tags: next.js

I don't know what is going on, npm run dev has no responese, and http://localhost:3000/ is blank page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndnXC.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiS8b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4W6M.png)

I try all day long ,install a lot of time,but still don't work.

Comment: "http://localhost:3000" did try manually running this one browser? because your server started already.. .. set default browser.. or go through manually put a url on browser..

Comment: I try "localhost:3000"  manually,but only get This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: simply type **yarn dev**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't post images of code, rather post the code itself. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12320578)

Comment: I try yarn dev, and it didn't work . I degrade to nextjs@12  and it works, I think it is 
 because next13 conflict with eslint.  I degarde nextjs@13 to @12, eslint to @8